# Passing parameter through function

Tags: python

I needed SQL-like DATEADD(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function to avoid using multiple if statements.

This is what I currently have:

```
def dateadd(interval, num, my_date):
    if isinstance(my_date, date):
        if interval == 'day':
            final_date = my_date + relativedelta(days = num)
        elif interval == 'month':
            final_date = my_date + relativedelta(months = num)
        return final_date
    else:
        'Not a date!'
        
today = dateadd('day', 0, datetime.today().date())
yesterday = dateadd('day', -1, today)
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve (to pass INTERVAL argument to dateadd function that would change parameter of relativedelta to days,months,years etc.):

```
def dateadd(INTERVAL, num, my_date):
    if isinstance(my_date, date):
        final_date = my_date + relativedelta(INTERVAL = num)
        return final_date
    else:
        'Not a date!'
```

Comment: AFAIK, named parameters cannot accept random strings, but you can try `relativedelta(**{INTERVAL: num})`

Comment: Alternatively, remove `interval` string entirely and just call `dateadd(relativedelta(... = num), my_date)` because you need to type `day` or `month` _anyway_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how it's done. Try this:

```
interval = {
    'month': num # or  'day': num
}
def dateadd(interval, my_date):
    if isinstance(my_date, date):
        final_date = my_date + relativedelta(**interval)
        return final_date
    else:
        return 'Not a date!'
```

Basically, you have to create a dictionary with parameter name as the key and parameter's value as the key's value. And then use `**` to unpack the value in the function's parameter.

Comment: Thank you! This actually helped me. I put the interval dictionary inside of the function so that the function is passing the arguments to dictionary which later on is used in relativedelta(**interval).